# derivative of quadratic function without transposes

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I'm trying to solve an equation of the following form:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial X} A'XA'X $$

where $X$ and $A$ are both equal-length column vectors (and so that $A'XA'A$ is scalar). From looking online I've seen derivatives of forms like $X'X$, but I'm unsure how it would work here when neither $X$ is transposed. My guess was

$$ 2A'AX $$

just to ensure that the derivative is also scalar, but I don't have confidence in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a scalar

$$b=A'X$$

Then you get

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial X}b^2=2b\frac{\partial b}{\partial X}$$

With

$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial X}=A$$

you finally get for the derivative

$$2bA=2(A'X)A$$

Comment: Do the dimensions work out there? Or are you ignoring the dimensions since $A'X$ is scalar? Otherwise, I see $1xp$ by $px1$ by $px1$.

Comment: The result is a scalar $2(A'X)$ times a vector $A$, so it does work out. Whether you write the result as a column or as a row doesn't matter.

Comment: So your answer and @flonk's answer are the same, effectively?

Comment: Yes, ALL answers are the same (which is a good thing ...) :)

Comment: @Josh I did not want to debate this technical thing too much, but I would like to add that both *can* be correct, but only one *is*. It just depends on how you defined $D/DX$. As operators are conventionally applied from the left side, the vector derivative is usually defined as a *row* vector $D/DX=[\partial_1...\partial_n]^T$, so  the application to a column becomes scalar and hence the derivative of a scalar becomes a row.

Comment: However, the motivation of my answer was to offer a formally different derivation, not to dispute the other posters.

Answer (score 0):

Two items; given a square symmetric matrix $B$ and a column vector $X$ that fits, the gradient of $X'BX,$ written as a column, is indeed $2BX.$

Next, the transpose of a one by one matrix is always itself; what else could it be? So $$  A'X = (A'X)' = X'A'' = X' A.  $$ As a result, your expression is
$$ A'X A' X = (A'X) A' X = X' A A' X = X' (A A') X.   $$
Taking symmetric square $B = A A'$ we get $X' B X.$

Your final expression needs to be $$  2 A A' X.  $$ Yours makes no sense; there is no such thing as $AX.$ If you meant $2(A'A)X$ it is still wrong.

I suggest you write this out in full detail for  dimension 1 and dimension 2. For dimension 2, give $A$ constant entries $a,b$ and give $X$ entries $x,y.$ As a column vector, what is the gradient of $(ax+by)^2 = a^2 x^2 + 2 a b x y + b^2 y^2?$

Using dot product, the gradient, as a row, is 
$$ 2 (A \cdot X) A',  $$
as a column
$$ 2 (A \cdot X) A.  $$

Answer (score 0):

As $(A'X)$ is a scalar, we can derive the $i$th component of that derivative as
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial X} A'XA'X\right)_i = \partial_i (A'XA'X) = \partial_i (A'X)^2 \overset{(1)}{=} 2(A'X) \partial_i A'X=2(A'X) \underbrace{\partial_i \sum_{k}A_k^* X_k}_{\displaystyle{=A_i^*}}$$ where we used the chain rule for (1) and hence 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X} A'XA'X=2(A'X)A'.$$

**Note** that this differs from the other answers, which give you a column vector $2(A'X)A$, hopefully I'm right :D

Comment: I think your answer makes the most sense, so far I believe now that the result should be a row vector, which yours is. (My original guess that it should be scalar is clearly wrong.) However, I'm concerned that I don't spot any errors in the other responses.

Comment: @flonk, all that matters is that, as a row vector and using dot product, you get $2 (A \cdot X) A',$ or as a column vector $2 (A \cdot X) A.$ You have that. All answers agree.

Comment: Agreed, the result can be written as a column or row, it just doesn't matter at all.